# EditText with suggestion list below

Tags: android, listview, rss, android-edittext

I want to implement a "Google instant" like list in my app. Having an editText on top and a list below it, that is updated every time the user types in a new character.

Can you point me to the right direction? Is there any widget or anything that I could use or do I have to drop the list and recreate it each time the users types something?

Thanks in advance
Mike

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)?

Comment: @CherylSimon Hey just a quick check if the AutoCompleteTextView is just auto complete the text or it comes with a list of suggestion below the edit text view?