# How to implement EditText with providing suggestion same like a Google search provides in Android application?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-edittext, google-search-api

I am trying to implement an ***EditText*** which takes a ***url*** from user and loads the desired url in the ***webview***. I have accomplished this task. Now I want to provide corresponding ***suggestions of urls*** on typing a word in the EditText same like as Google provides. I have a sample application from google play store which has implemented this scenario.

***URL to the app:*** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=video.downloader.videodownloader&hl=en

I have searched every where to find a clue to start my work. But I couldn't find anything supportive.

Screen Shots for figuring out the Scenario:

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJYQ2.png)

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhayH.png)

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omRJ0.png)

I am not using any database to fetch data from and to show in suggestion. I want to use EditText like an address bar of Google browser. When a user tap and type any word, it gives suggested urls respectively as showing in the screen shots.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: How would we use this piece of code to search in google urls..? As its getting suggestions from wikipedia. I changed the url with "https://www.google.com" inside String urlString and run again the app. Its not showing any suggestion. 

Thanks for your notice..

Comment: this is your job to provide your data - i have no idea where you want to get suggestions from...

Comment: Kindly, check screen shots. It will give you an idea about figuring out my question.

Comment: did you run my code **without** any changes (just **^C** and **^V**)? does it look sinilar? if so, the only thing you have to do is to access your custom `Uri` and get the suggestions from that `Uri`

Comment: Yes, I did run it. It looks comparable.

Comment: so i hope you know what to do next

Comment: What do you mean by accessing custom uri??

Comment: where do you want to get your searching suggestions from? from some `Uri`, right? so you have to access that `Uri` and parse the `json` / `xml` / `whatever` response

Comment: I want to retrieve suggestion from Google Custom Search.
Custom Search JSON API. How would I use it over here?

See this : " https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview "

Comment: so use `Google Custom Search` instead of `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php` which i used to get my suggestion from

Comment: Can you kindly show me, what exactly should I do?

Comment: what is your `Google Custom Search` uri? for example in my case if you search for string `europe` the uri is: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=europe&limit=8&namespace=0&format=json

Comment: Have you checked the screen shots I uploaded?

Comment: By Google Custom Search I mean Custom Search JSON API

The Custom Search JSON API lets you develop websites and applications to retrieve and display search results from Google Custom Search programmatically. With this API, you can use RESTful requests to get either web search or image search results in JSON format.

Read this: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: Yeah, I will try to follow all the explanations.
Thank you for your kind informations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText with suggestion list below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903763/edittext-with-suggestion-list-below)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a search interface (documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/) with a Content Provider. You should fill the content provider by using custom search JSON API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview. It's a quite complicated task but I think you should start with this stack

Comment: I think your answer can help me. But I couldn't follow your suggestion. Can you help me what exactly should I do, to come with solution?

Thanks for your kind suggestion.